# looking for paragraphs that contain a list of words

Tags: sed, grep

I have a list of words in a file called pattern.txt.
I need to search paragraphs of an input stream that contain ALL the word in the list. For a single word (foo) in paragraph I normally use the sed code:

```
sed   '/./{H;$!d;}; x;/foo/!d'
```

But I don't know how to do this operation for a list of words.

Comment: DoOn't use the word "pattern" in this context as it's ambiguous. Please read [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand the issue and then [edit] your question to clearly state what you want to do with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```bash
$ cat patterns.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

```bash
$ cat file
first paragraph foo bar

second baz bar foo

third

fourth foo baz bar

fifth baz foo
```

Here `cat file` represents the input stream:

```bash
$ cat file | gawk '
    NR == FNR {pattern[++n] = $0; next}
    ENDFILE {RS = ""; ORS = "\n\n"}
    {for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) if ($0 !~ pattern[i]) next; print}
' patterns.txt -   # note the trailing hyphen
second baz bar foo

fourth foo baz bar
```

`RS = ""` changes awk to read empty-line-separated paragraphs as a record.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'for slurp.split("\n\n") { .put if (/foo/ & /bar/ & /baz/) };'  file
```

OR

```
~$ raku -e 'for slurp.split("\n\n") { .put if all(/foo/, /bar/,  /baz/) };'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. Above, the file is `slurp`ed in (i.e. read all at once), splitting on `\n\n` paragraphs. These paragraph elements are iterated over using `for`, and `if` there are matches to the appropriate regexes (using a `&` Boolean **and** Operator), the paragraph is out`put`. The second code example is similar to the first but features Raku's new "Junction" operator, `all`. There are four "Junction" operators in Raku: `all`, `any`, `one`, and `none`.

*Note: if paragraphs are separated by two-or-more newlines, use `split` with a regex argument, as in `.split( / \n ** 2..* / )`.*

---

Sample Input (thanks to @glenn_jackman):

```
first paragraph foo bar

second baz bar foo

third

fourth foo baz bar

fifth baz foo
```

Sample Output:

```
second baz bar foo
fourth foo baz bar
```

---

***Taking "patterns" as an input file:***  If you don't want to write-out the pattern-matching above, you can prepend your code above with a whitespace-separated list (see the first link at bottom for "word-quoting" options):

```
~$ raku -e 'my @words = <foo bar baz> ; for slurp.trim.split("\n\n") { .put if .match: all @words };'  file
```

Or you can read "patterns" directly from a file (assuming one "pattern" per line, as in the answer by @glenn_jackman):

```
~$ raku -e 'my @words = "patterns.txt".IO.lines; for slurp.trim.split("\n\n") { .put if .match: all @words };'  file
```

If you just have whitespace-separated "words" that you want to use as a test-pattern input file, then the above input line simplifies to:

`my @words = "patterns.txt".IO.words;`

---

https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting
https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN {chomp(@patterns = <STDIN>); $/ = ""}
  for $p (@patterns) {next LINE unless /$p/}
  print' -- your-file < patterns.txt
```

Note that patterns are interpreted as perl regular expressions, not basic regular expressions like in `sed` or extended regular expressions like in `awk`. They're mostly backward compatible with extended regular expressions.

Note however that by default `.` won't match newline characters. You can add the `s` flag (`/$p/s` instead of `/$p/`) to change that.

Other than that, if they work in `awk`, they'll more than  likely work in `perl`. They have many many extensions over BRE or ERE, some of which useful to match within paragraphs. For instance `(?m)^foo$` would match on paragraphs that contain a line being exactly `foo`. perl regexps have become a de-facto standard and most of its extensions are available in most modern programming languages including python, php and all the ones using PCRE or PCRE2.